# Problem in doing conditional probability.

Tags: probability

I can't solve a problem which is

> A total of $n$ shells is fired at a target. The probability of $j$-th shell hitting the target is $P_j$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Assuming that the $n$ events are mutually independent find the probability that at least two shells out of $n$ will find the target.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: You should post your attempt for the problem.

Comment: $P(\text{at least two}) = 1 - [P(\text{none}) + P(\text{exactly one})]$

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_j$ denote the event that the $j$-th shell hits the target and $A$ be the event that at least two shells out of $n$ will hit the target. Then, by independence, your can calculate your probability with
\begin{align*}
P(A) = & 1 - [P(\text{none of the shell will find tharget}) + P(\text{only one shell out of n will find the target}) \\
= & 1 - P(A_1^c \cap \cdots \cap A_n^c) - (P(A_1 \cap A_2^c \cdots \cap A_n^c) + \cdots + P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cdots \cap A_n)) \\
= & 1- \prod_{j = 1}^n (1 - P_j) - \sum_{j = 1}^n \prod_{k \neq j} P_j(1 - P_k).
\end{align*}